# Make Choices to Enable / Disable Net Adapter Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, adapter

I'm Trying to use Powershell to make a choices to Enable/Disable Net Adapter "Ethernet"
I Coded This

```
$caption = "Choose Action";
$message = "What do you want to do?";
$enab = start-process powershell -verb runas -argument D:\ena.ps1
$disa = start-process powershell -verb runas -argument D:\dis.ps1
$choices = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($enab,$disa);
$answer = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($caption,$message,$choices,0)
switch ($answer){
0 {"You entered Enable"; break}
1 {"You entered Disable"; break}
}
```

Error :

> Object cannot be stored in an array of this type.
>   At D:\Untitled4.ps1:5 char:1
>   + $choices = System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[];
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidCastException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidCastException
>
> Exception calling "PromptForChoice" with "4" argument(s): "Value
>   cannot be null. Parameter name: choices" At D:\Untitled4.ps1:6 char:1
>   + $answer = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($caption,$message,$choices,0)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

I have failed before this to do On/Off script using powershell (if the net adapter is enable then disable it and vice versa. is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730939.aspx I think what you want to be doing is the following:

```powershell
$caption = "Choose action:"
$message = "What state do you want for the network adapter?"

$enable = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Enable", `
    "Enables the Network Adapter"

$disable = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Disable", `
    "Disables the Network Adapter"

$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($enable, $disable)

$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($caption, $message, $options, 0) 

switch ($result)
{
    0 { 
        "You selected Enable." 
        start-process powershell -verb runas -argument D:\ena.ps1
    }
    1 {
        "You selected Disable."
        start-process powershell -verb runas -argument D:\dis.ps1
    }
}
```

The approach you were taking wasn't working because you were trying to assign a `process` to a `ChoiceDescription` array. In the example above, you have to first create two `ChoiceDescription` objects before assigning them to the array

Comment: Thank you it worked , and i noticed the mistake i made